# how to add Replicate api key?

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, replicate

i´m trying to use [Replicate](https://replicate.com/) to run some neural networks in the cloud but it yields this error message:

```
ReplicateError: No API token provided. You need to set the REPLICATE_API_TOKEN environment variable or create a client with `replicate.Client(api_token=...)`.

You can find your API key on https://replicate.com
```

and python also can´t find it with the command

```
print(os.environ.get("REPLICATE_API_TOKEN"))
```

i already tried passing it using `sysdm.cpl` and it still doesnt work. How do I set it as an environmental variable?

Comment: i already did exactly that and tried setting it in 2 different ways. stackoverflow is my last resort!!!

Answer (score 8):

you can set the api key within the python

```
import os
import replicate

#Set the REPLICATE_API_TOKEN environment variable
os.environ["REPLICATE_API_TOKEN"] = "your_api_token_here"
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue when trying to run Llama. Here is my solution:

```
os.environ["REPLICATE_API_TOKEN"] = "TOKEN"
api = replicate.Client(api_token=os.environ["REPLICATE_API_TOKEN"])
output = api.run(
    "meta/llama-2-70b-chat:02e509c789964a7ea8736978a43525956ef40397be9033abf9fd2badfe68c9e3",
        input={"prompt": prompt}
    )
for item in output:
    print(item, end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

Was also getting an auth issue. This is what worked -
`replicate = replicate.Client(api_token='')`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
from replicate.client import Client

replicate = Client(api_token="<your_token>")
```

(Note the difference; it is `replicate.client.Client`)

Source: https://github.com/replicate/replicate-python/issues/58

Answer (score 0):

You can also set environment variables via terminal.
In powershell it would be:

```
$env:VARIABLE_NAME='VARIABLE_VALUE'
```

Answer (score 0):

ReplicateError: You did not pass an authentication token

---

ReplicateError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 output = Completion(prompt="The typical color of llama is:")

3 frames
 in Completion(prompt)
2
3 def Completion(prompt):
----> 4   output = replicate.run(
5       llama2_13b,
6       input={"prompt":prompt}

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/replicate/client.py in run(self, model_version, **kwargs)
122         version_id = match.group("version")
123
--> 124         prediction = self.predictions.create(version=version_id, **kwargs)
125
126         if owner and name:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/replicate/prediction.py in create(self, version, input, webhook, webhook_completed, webhook_events_filter, stream, **kwargs)
208             body["stream"] = "true"
209
--> 210         resp = self._client._request(
211             "POST",
212             "/v1/predictions",

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/replicate/client.py in _request(self, method, path, **kwargs)
79
80         if 400 <= resp.status_code < 600:
---> 81             raise ReplicateError(resp.json()["detail"])
82
83         return resp